# How to change the limit of items in an action bar

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I have an app that utilizes Action Bar Sherlock and has 5 icons at the bottom(split when narrow). On most devices, the 5 icons are visible but on Motorola RazR or in emulator with long screen ratio and xhdpi(540x960), only 4 icons are visible and I guess that's what they call an overflow.

What I can't understand is that even if I set the icons to very small images, enough for 5 to fit on the screen, the RazR only shows 4 with wide spaces in between.

Is there a limit that can be changed so that I can forceably display all 5 icons on the bottom? Thanks!

(I don't want to post long unrelated junk of codes here so just tell me what part do you want to see)

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, looks like It is impossible to change. On this document [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

The number of icons is dependent to its screen density.

Looks like the best solution is to have your custom made bottom menu bar.